# Event on DIV change in Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am fairly new to Javascript but I am trying to write a Greasemonkey script to modify the contents of a `DIV` to add more information. The contents I am trying to modify may be changed by the existing code of the site. Is there anyway I could trigger an event when this happens? Otherwise I will have to run it on a interval which is less responsive and is less efficient.

Comment: If you're lucky the website is calling a function to update the div. Maybe you can replace that function with a function that calls the original function and then adds your content. See also

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom